# Scipy's pdist correlation metric not same as numpy corrcoef

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, correlation

I used scipy's pdist with the correlation metric to construct a correlation matrix, but the values were not matching the ones I obtained from numpy's corrcoef.

I applied pdist on a very simple two 1-d arrays of the same values: [1,2,3] and [1,2,3]:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]).transpose()
print np.corrcoef(df)
print squareform(pdist(df, metric='correlation'))
```

Instead of outputting a correlation value of 1, I got 2.2E-16 from the pdist:

```
[[ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]

[[  0.00000000e+00   2.22044605e-16]
 [  2.22044605e-16   0.00000000e+00]]
```

The following is the code I found in scipy for their correlation metric:

```
umu = u.mean()
vmu = v.mean()
um = u - umu
vm = v - vmu
dist = 1.0 - np.dot(um, vm) / (norm(um) * norm(vm))
```

Comment: Do you mean `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)?   Please show the exact code that gave you the unexpected result (i.e. something we can copy and run ourselves).

Comment: "Correlation distance" is not the same as the correlation coefficient.  A "distance" between two equal points is *supposed* to be 0.  (If you google "correlation distance", note that there is yet another concept, the "distance correlation", which is not the same as the "correlation distance".)

Comment: Might as well make my comment an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Correlation distance" is not the same as the correlation coefficient.  A "distance" between two equal points is *supposed* to be 0.  (If you search for "correlation distance", note that there is yet another concept, the "distance correlation", which is not the same as the "correlation distance".)

Comment: correlation distance is also just [1 - correlation coefficient] !